Reference DLL in Visual Studio under Assemblies not working
I have been used to being able to reference an in-development DLL (alpha, pre-release) in another project on my local machine. This can be handy for pre-release integration testing. Usually right-click the Dependencies node in Solution Explorer, browse to the DLL and choose OK. Lately I have noticed that while VS does not complain, it refuses to find objects from that DLL. Even searching in Object Viewer returns nothing.
I'm referencing a netstandard2.1 DLL in a net8 project.
As a workaround I have figured out how to overwrite the DLL in my .nuget cache but obviously that's a recipe for complete confusion.
Did something change that I missed?

So the solution which was taking a dependency on the DLL had a Test project which was still taking a dependency upon the latest release version of my DLL. Once I also replaced that dependency to use my alpha version it all works.
